# Создание и получение доступа к одному и тому же экземпляру AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, java-ee

Есть веб приложение. Есть класс, аннотированный как @Configuration в котором описаны бины. Из любой части приложения можно получить доступ к контексту так:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
```

Однако каждый раз создается новый экземпляр.

Как можно создать один экземпляр `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`'a при старте приложения, и по мере необходимости получать к нему доступ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему вы это можете достать в любом компоненте, так как это bean:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

Comment: Мне нужно его получить из контроллера во время работы веб приложения. Т.е. приложение стартует - создается AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, который сканирует все бины в SrpingConfig.class. Когда прилетает запрос, я имею доступ к нему, а через него к бинам. Возможно именно Anotation не обязателен, есть еще Web контекст, и он может быть лучше подойдет, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Так в чем проблема в контроллере его достать через @Autowired? Ведь контроллер тоже Бин. Или я чего-то не пойму?